# Can EPF be withdrawn at this time?

Tags: india, retirement-plan, provident-fund

I am considering to withdraw my EPF account, will the return amount be lower if removed now, than waiting for the future as my current situation is bad , as i am leaving my organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no penalty for early withdrawal if you are not having any job.

If you do not withdraw, the interest will keep getting accumulated.